# Solving circular dependencies in Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I've struggling with clean up our code base from circular dependencies for a while now, but in a few cases I cannot find a way to get around circular dependencies without change the way components are currently built.

Example:

```
// parent.component.ts
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
...
@ContentChildren() items: ChildComponent

#################################################################

// child.component.ts
import { ParentComponent} from './parent.component';
...
constructor(@Host() private parentComponent: ParentComponent) { }
```

In the above case, must I refactor the code to use a service instead or is there any other way to get rid of circular dependencies?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to communicate between components: inputs, outputs, services. Injecting components into each other is a big code smell. Read https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.

Comment: This might help you where you are injecting a class of the same type: https://angular.io/api/core/SkipSelf

Comment: If you really want to stick to core angular, yes service is the correct way to go. But if you are open to for other packages, you can look at `inversify`. It would help in reducing circular dependencies a lot. I am currently using it in my project.

Comment: I'd suggest using only the `@ContentChildren() items: ChildComponent` and in the `ChildComponent` update any code using `parentComponent` to emit `@Output()` events for the parent to listen to ie 'push' to the parent component.

Comment: @bjorkblom in the case you show here, it doesn't look like circular dependencies are actually causing any issues? (I think TypeScript just erases the parent component import from the child component since you're not directly instantiating a parent component) Are there any real issues? Or do you just dislike the way the code is structured? If there are real issues, it might help to add that detail. If you dislike this code structure, add the detail about the ideal you're trying to achieve and what's preventing you from getting there.

Answer (score 0):

For TS Classes you can do this:

```
export class Child{
    _parent;
    constructor(parent)
    {
    this._parent = parent
    }

    get parent(): ParentClass { return this._parent}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Typically, you can get around circular dependencies by injecting `Injector` and requesting a dependency from it not in constructor, but in `ngOnInit` or whenever you would really need to use it.